# VBA Excel Clearing

Tags: excel, vba

The following code works but runs too slowly on large files, so the code needs to be modified to identify the first year that is earlier than 2019 and then delete that row and the row containing the rest of the years below that, all at one time:

```
Range("B2").Select
  Do Until ActiveCell.Value =""
    If ActiveCell.Value < 2019 Then
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
Else
    ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).Select
End If
Loop
```

Code Problem: data sets can have 1000's of rows so checking every cell is very slow. Since the data is always in order, all I need to do is find the first entry <2019 and then select `xldown` and delete everything, but I don't know how to find that cell and make it the active cell.

Comment: Use `Application.Match`.

Comment: Another option is to use `Range.AutoFilter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as stated in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60554215/vba-excel-clearing/60554457#comment107129004_60554215):

```
Dim firstrow As Variant
firstrow = Application.Match(2018, ActiveSheet.Range("B:B"), -1)

If Not IsError(firstrow) Then
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    ActiveSheet.Rows(firstrow + 1 & ":" & lastrow).Delete
End If
```

Comment: Hmmm I might have spoken hastily on the Match suggestion, because it doesn't sound like 2018 is guaranteed to exist in the data set: "first year that is earlier than 2019."

Comment: Well maybe you could do `Application.Match(2018, ActiveSheet.Range("B:B"),-1)` and then `+1` to get the row after it.

Comment: @BigBen `firstrow = Application.Match(2019, ActiveSheet.Range("B:B"), 1)` is probably more accurate.

Comment: Yep - I was waffling back and forth on that one. Well don't you want `-1`, because it sounds like the years are in descending order? Should definitely be `2019` though.

Comment: @BigBen nope that did not work.  moved back to `-1`

Comment: The problem happens if `2018` exists in the column... then it won't get deleted, because of the `firstrow +1`. That's why I was saying `2019`.